# nftables (nft) chain priority issues

Tags: debian, nftables

`nft` is causing me endless headaches, no matter how I tweak the policy, I still cannot get it to function.

The concept I have in mind :

- One "base" chain where common rules live (e.g. allow `ssh` etc.)
- One or more application specific where daemon specific rules live (e.g. http server chain)

I have tried many different permutations of rules, but I can never get both "base" + daemon traffic flowing, I always end up blocking one or the other ! ;-(

Here is my current (simplified) config (as presently constituted it allows `ssh` but fails to allow `http`)

/etc/nftables.conf:

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
flush ruleset                                                                                                                       
table inet filter {   
     counter input_ssh {}     
        set my_admin_ipv4 {                                                                                                        
                type ipv4_addr                                                                                                      
                flags interval                                                                                                      
                counter                                                                                                             
                elements = {                                                                                                        
                        10.0.0.0/8,                                                                                                 
                        172.16.0.0/12,                                                                                              
                        192.168.0.0/16                                                                                                                                                                                      
                }                                                                                                                   
        }         
       chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter;
                iifname lo accept comment "Allow loopback traffic";
                ct state established,related accept comment "Allow established/related connections";
                ct state invalid drop comment "Deny invalid connections";

                # SSH
                tcp dport ssh ip saddr @my_admin_ipv4 counter name input_ssh accept comment "Allow IPv4 SSH from Admin";
    policy drop;
        }
        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority 0;
                policy drop;
        }
        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority 0;
        }
 include "/etc/nft/*.conf"
}
```

/etc/nft/http.conf:

```
counter input_http {} 
   chain http {
    type filter hook input priority filter - 1;
      # HTTP #
      tcp dport {80,443} counter name input_nginx accept comment "Allow HTTP";
    policy accept; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to mark packets to be accepted as a safe conduct in following chains of the same hook.

- each accept rule should mark the packet

  Rules doing an explicit accept should mark the packet right before accepting it. Any occurence of:

  ```
  ... accept
  ```

  should be replaced with:

  ```
  ... meta mark set 0xf00 accept
  ```

  The value isn't important as long it's not 0 if there's no other role to the mark.
- each chain should accept a marked packet since that's the safe conduct

  by using this rule early in the chain:

  ```
  meta mark != 0 accept
  ```

That's the general idea. Adaptations and exceptions can still be made if it makes more sense.

Here is the revisited ruleset following this approach. The mark is accepted after the `ct ... invalid drop` rule which is an important rule that should not be bypassed (and could actually have been done in an earlier chain once and for all since it's a drop rule). If below, input is the last chain in the filter/input hook it's not really needed to mark accepted packets, but it doesn't hurt to do so.

`/etc/nftables.conf:`:

```
flush ruleset 
table inet filter {   
    counter input_ssh {}     
    set my_admin_ipv4 {                                                                                                        
        type ipv4_addr                                                                                                      
        flags interval                                                                                                      
        counter                                                                                                             
        elements = {                                                                                                        
            10.0.0.0/8,                                                                                                 
            172.16.0.0/12,                                                                                              
            192.168.0.0/16                                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                   
    }         
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        iifname lo meta mark set 0x1 accept comment "Allow loopback traffic";
        ct state established,related meta mark set 0x1 accept comment "Allow established/related connections";
        ct state invalid drop comment "Deny invalid connections";
        meta mark != 0 accept

        # SSH
        tcp dport ssh ip saddr @my_admin_ipv4 counter name input_ssh meta mark set 0x1 accept comment "Allow IPv4 SSH from Admin";
    }
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;                      
    }
    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy accept;
    }
    include "/etc/nft/*.conf"
}
```

`/etc/nft/http.conf` (replaced `counter_nginx` with `counter_http`). The `meta mark != 0 accept` rule is probably not needed here since there might not be any other chain before anyway, but it doesn't hurt to have it too.

```
    counter input_http {} 
    chain http {
        type filter hook input priority filter - 1; policy accept;
         meta mark != 0 accept
         # HTTP #
         tcp dport {80,443} counter name input_http meta mark set 0x2 accept comment "Allow HTTP";
    }
```

This method uses marks so will be harder to integrate with other firewall rules that were already using marks for other purposes. It's still possible by reserving a few bits of the mark with bitwise operations.

Comment: This looks interesting, I will test and let you know. But one question, I see you've changed `policy drop` to `policy accept` on the main input filter ? Surely this means anything unmatched gets accepted ?

Comment: Typo with cut/pastes (and simplification of the initial answer using a dedicated "verdict" chain). I'll put back drop.

Comment: I see, so you're saying there could be a third chain with nothing in it apart from `policy drop` and `meta mark != 0 accept`  ? I guess that perhaps makes it cleaner in a way.  I'm just loading up the config now, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be showing me the love (have updated the original Q with the fresh syntax).  SSH is working but not web.

Comment: Interesting that the missing `set` was not picked up by `nft -c -f /etc/nftables.conf` ? But now it works !

Comment: meta mark is an expression (the equivalent of iptables' match) while meta mark set is a statement (the equivalent of iptables' target, except it's not terminal for the rule). Both are valid.